# Storing numbers in array is confusing how to manipulate those items based on value, not index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm losing my mind on this one. My last question answered a syntax issue, but did not address making it function properly, so here goes...

My object:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": [],
            "Gender": [],
            "NEWSEC": [],
            "Telco_Segment": []
    };
```

My function:

```
function buildFacets(key, val)
{
    if(key == 'country')
    {   
        filter.country = val;
    }
    else
    {
        if(val in filter[key])
        {
            delete filter[key][val];
        }
        else
        {
            filter[key].push(val);
        }
    }

    console.log(filter);
}
```

My problem is my function is comparing the incoming value to the array indexes, not the array values. For instance, if I call buildFacets("Age Group",2) I will get a value in that array of 2. However, if I call it again, it will just add another value of '2' to the array instead of removing the '2' that is already there because it's comparing to the index, which is 0.

I hope I'm explaining this right. Please let me know if it needs clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var idx = filter[key].indexOf(value);

if(idx != -1)
{
    filter[key].splice(idx, 1);
}
else
{
    filter[key].push(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery to the rescue, but I'd love to know what the non-jQuery solution is:

```
function buildFacets(key, val)
{
    var pos = -1;

    if(key == 'country')
    {   
        filter.country = val;
    }
    else
    {
        pos = $.inArray(val, filter[key]);

        if(pos > -1)
        {
            filter[key].splice(pos,1);
        }
        else
        {
            filter[key].push(val);
        }
    }

    console.log(filter);
}
```

**EDIT/UPDAT**E (non jQuery version, thanks to xvatar

```
function buildFacets(key, val)
{
    var pos = -1;

    if(key == 'country')
    {   
        filter.country = val;
    }
    else
    {
        pos = filter[key].indexOf(val);

        if(pos > -1)
        {
            filter[key].splice(pos,1);
        }
        else
        {
            filter[key].push(val);
        }
    }

    console.log(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` operator tests if the object has a given property, it does not check for membership.